# Reading a word from a file overloading operator >>

Tags: c++

I want to overload the operator >>, so I can read some data from a file to save it in my class. My problem is that I don't know how to read one single word. Does a function like get() or getline() exist for this purpose?

For example, I have this class:

```
class Person{
private:
      char * name; 
      int id;
public:
....
```

I have this file with some info:

James 23994

Anne 23030

Mary 300392

And what I want is to read the name and the id of these people to save them in my class.

Comment: To begin with, use `std::string` for your strings and it will become much simpler. And if you have ever used `>>` together with `std::cin` then you already know how to read a "word".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things are easier if you use `std::string` instead of a bare pointer that requires you to allocate memory, keep track of the size (or rely on null-termination), etc...

```
struct Person {
    std::string name;
    int id;
};
```

Now you can use the already existing `operator<<` for `std::string` and `int` :

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, Person& p) {
    in >> p.name >> p.id;
    return in;
}
```

Note that `operator>>` does read input until it finds a `' '` by default, hence to "read a word" you dont have to do anything extra.

If you insist on having private fields, you should declare the operator as friend of the class.

Comment: Don't need two statements in the overloaded operator, can just do `return in >> p.name >> p.id;`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I have a small trauma on this from unclear error messages, hence I am used to put it on two lines ;), but you are right of course